# javascript createElement/append child -- new text dissapears after click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript method that creates a bunch of elements on click. When I call it from a button, it only stays on the screen for the duration of that click. when I enter the exact same code into the console, however, it stays on the page until I reload or navigate away (which is exactly what I want).

JavaScript code: (it's the only method in the js file)

```
function post() {
var postTitle = document.createElement('h3');
var nodeTitle = document.createTextNode('Immigration is good.');
postTitle.appendChild(nodeTitle);
etc....
```

Where I'm calling it in the html:

```
<input type="submit" id="post-button" value="Post" onclick="post()">
```

The script tag is in the header of the html page.

How do I get it to stay on the page past the duration of the click? Any ideas why it's being immediately obliterated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to cancel the form's submission. A `return false;` from post, if it exists, won't work because the `onclick` attribute is calling `post()` but not returning anything.

You could change it to `onclick="return post();"`, but it would be better to attach the handler directly, and to the `submit` event of the form and not the `click` event of the button (people do use <kbd>Enter</kbd> sometimes!):

```
document.getElementById('some-form').onclick = post;
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks. Why is return=false necessary? Does that tell the browser not to refresh the page?

Comment: @Skitterm `return false` from an event handler tells the browser two things: stop the event from bubbling up the DOM, and cancel the event's default behavior. The default behavior of your submit button is to submit, which the `return false` cancels.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what the button does. It is posting!

When you click the button it is redirecting you back to the page you are currently on! It seems like it is showing up and disappearing what is actually happening though is that the page is refreshing.

There are a couple of options to do what you want. Submitting via Ajax or having your server respond with a hashbang/cookie set to direct the page to do as you wish.